# Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel

I want to open the default authentication provided by Laravel to my REST API. For this I am creating `POST http://localhost:8080/api/login`:

```php
// In api.php
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

However, sending a POST request to this address gives me a runtime error in `/media/Data/workspaces/git/mahlzeit/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php`:

```
RuntimeException
Session store not set on request.
```

The payload I am sending is

```
{"name": "test", "password": "123456", "email": "test@test.com"}
```

although I don't think that's important here.

So.. the standard login for laravel is working - I don't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: You shouldn't be using session login for api though. Check [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) and google a bit on laravel api to see best practices. If you look at the `app/Http/Kernel.php` you will see that **api middleware group** doesn't have session...

Comment: @ljubadr Not sure if I understand: I should not use session login for api?

Comment: I wouldn't... this explains it nicely [the ins and outs of token based authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication)

Comment: [Cookies vs Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/)

Comment: [Sessions vs. Token based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200413/sessions-vs-token-based-authentication)

Comment: Google out **api session vs tokens** and do a bit of research

Comment: Maybe in your case, session would be enough, if you plan to use your api with your website only... good luck :)

Comment: @ljubadr It's supposed to work as a backend for mobile apps ^^ I probably have to give it a ready first - I thought it's enough to use something like a cookie or whatever which I exchange after authentication with the client ^^

Comment: Check if you will have access to cookies in your mobile app. If you do, you could modify `app/Http/Kernel.php` - `$middlewareGroups` **'api'=> [...]** to use `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`