# Confusion about Cookie Authentication vs Token Authentication, what is the difference exactly?

Tags: authentication, security, session, cookies, token

I read [Token Authentication vs. Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000835/token-authentication-vs-cookies) and [Sessions vs. Token based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200413/sessions-vs-token-based-authentication).

I also read [How do you use HTTP cookies, sessions, and tokens for web authentication and authorization?](https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/how-do-you-use-http-cookies-sessions-tokens-web) and [Cookies vs. Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://dzone.com/articles/cookies-vs-tokens-the-definitive-guide)

But all the answers there and all the points made in those two articles make me even more confused about the difference between Cookie Authentication vs Token Authentication(not JWT in particular), especially from the authentication process point of view. After all, both methods will return an encrypted string from the server and the server will verify that string after that.

I have a project that implemented "token authentication" in the following way,

1. User enters their login credentials. The server verifies the credentials
   are correct and returns a "token", a long encrypted string. The token has an expiration time.
2. This token is stored in user browser's local storage. The server also stores this token along with the user's other information, mostly his privileges.
3. Subsequent requests to the server include this token in a customized request header field.
4. The server first verifies the token is correct then verifies the privileges info to see if he/she can access the requested resources.
5. Once a user logs out, the token is deleted from both the client and server side.

I know the obvious difference from Cookie Authentication is that the cookie is stored in the browser's cookie and the cookie will have attributes like [name/path/domain/httponly...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) defined in MDN. The cookie will be sent by browser **automatically** while our client js codes need to add the token in every request.

But other than that what is the difference? I am also quite confused that people always say using cookie to do **session control**. I see people use **Session-based** Authentication and **Cookie-based** Authentication interchangeably as if Token Authentication can NOT do session control (and is stateless, therefore).

Apparently, our codes use a token to do "session control". If the request doesn't contain a valid token or the privileges are not enough it will be rejected. When a user logs out, the token is deleted and the next time he logs in the server will give him a new token.

I have always thought that during the time a user is logged in we are doing some kind of session control (until he logs out).

And my last question is (other than the difference) is there any potential problem with our token authentication and its "session control"? (I suspect this project was created a long time ago and having mobile clients then, when sending cookies from mobile apps was not easy but I can't confirm this.)

I attach a network request picture here to make my process clearer. During the login there is a request to get a token from the server, then each request after that will contain the token header.

[image: token process]

Comment: You say "not JWT in particular", but if we take token to mean something similar in nature at least, regardless the specific implementation - then I would say, the main difference is that the token can contain (encrypted) information itself, whereas a mere session ID is a "dumb" thing, that can only identify a particular set of stored data. Token = created based on a specific set of data, session id = random value, only used as an identifier. (That a token _could_ serve the same purpose of providing a unique identifier to associate session data, is of course true regardless.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I said "not JWT in particular" for 2 reasons. I want to know token authentication in general.  token authentication surely isn't just JWT, right? (so I don't want JWT to sidetrack my question). Our implementation does not use JWT and my question is also about our implementation.

Comment: Your comments also confirm (or add my question), that my question is "cookie vs token and why do people always say to use cookie for session control as if token can not do session control? And your comments seem to compare session id to token (and therefore confirm others words).

Comment: You say your token was _"a long encrypted string"_ - so if that actually contains _decryptable_ information, that's a major difference to a mere session ID right there. Even without having access to any session data stored on the server side, there would be information you could extract from the token itself in _any_ context, just as long as key and algorithm for that encryption are known.

Comment: I added a network picture to make our process more clear. The token string doesn't contain a session ID per se.  The server compares the token and gets the user's privileges to check if he can access the resource or not.

Answer (score 1):

One difference that immediately comes to mind is that cookies are standardized (e.g., in RFC 6265). They are therefore well-tested to work across different vendors. A reason for using custom tokens may be the need to communicate in protocols other than HTTP.

The session control question appears to be about the ability to constantly change the token. You can return a new token in every API response and only allow it to authorize a few subsequent requests. Cookies are usually constant for a long period of time, you can copy them onto different HTTP clients and get parallel access from there - that's probably what is referred to as a session not under control.

Comment: Yes I can't find an agreed-upon definition of session control. But I had thought during the time a user is logged in we are doing some kind of **session control** (until he logs out.)